# Arrows are shifted left tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, anchor

I am having some issues recreating these Work breakdown structure. I have seen one similar example from TeXample.net (here [source](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/work-breakdown-structure/)), but I am still not getting the exact thing like in the picture below.

The arrow is still shifted, even after I adjusted the shifted left and right.

Here my ideas:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees}

\definecolor{box-up}{HTML}{ffe6cc}
\definecolor{box-down}{HTML}{dae8fe}


\tikzset{
    basic/.style  = {draw, text width=6cm,text height=4mm,rectangle,rounded corners=4pt}, 
    root/.style   = {basic, thin, align=center, fill=box-up!90, double=box-up},
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=80mm,text width=6cm, text height=5mm},
    level 2/.style = {basic, thin,align=center, fill=box-up!70, text width=8em},
    level 3/.style = {basic, thin, align=center, fill=box-up!50, text width=7em}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
align=center,
edge from parent fork down,
edge from parent/.style={->,draw},
>=latex]

\node[root] {Header}
child {node[level 2] (c1) {Element 1}}
child {node[level 2] (c2) {Element 2}};

\begin{scope}[
anchor = south,
every node/.style={level 3},
edge from parent fork down
]

\node [below right of = c1, yshift=-5pt, xshift=5pt] (c11) {Element 11};
%\node [below left of = c1] (c12) {Element 12};


\node [below of = c2, xshift=15pt] (c21) {Element 21};
\node [below of = c21] (c22) {Element 22};
\node [below of = c22] (c23) {Element 23};
\node [below of = c23] (c24) {Element 24};


\end{scope}

% lines from each level 1 node to every one of its "children"

\draw[->] (c1.195) |- (c11.west);
%\draw[->] (c1.195) |- (c12.west);



\draw[->] (c2.195) |- (c21.west);
\draw[->] (c2.195) |- (c22.west);
\draw[->] (c2.195) |- (c23.west);
\draw[->] (c2.195) |- (c24.west);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I put everything south, but the arrows are pointing left. How can I do this exactly?

Here what it should look like:
[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome. It's a bit unclear what you mean by "put everything south, but the arrows are pointing left". Are you referring to the fact that the arrow going down from Element 1 doesn't start at the midpoint of the Element 1 node? That is because you start it at `c1.195`. The `.195` means it takes the point on the boundary of the node that is at an angle of 195 degrees, i.e. west-south west. With `c1.south` instead the arrow will start at the middle of the bottom middle of the node, but you'll need to shift Element 11 more to the right.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Hey! Thank you for that, it worked just fine with that tip! :) But I am not able create a new raw like the picture. I am only getting: Header Level 1 and the branches in blue. The four blocks next to each other aren't appearing even though I added a new Level 4 to \tikset. Do you have an idea how I could create that? ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

added -- `rounded corners` at root level

edited correct syntax is `below=of...` and not `below of=...`

edited code for `south anchor` at level 1

you may like to see the following tree  -- https://texample.net/tikz/examples/family-tree/

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees}

\definecolor{box-up}{HTML}{ffe6cc}
\definecolor{box-down}{HTML}{dae8fe}


\tikzset{
    basic/.style  = {draw, text width=6cm,text height=4mm,rectangle,rounded corners=4pt}, 
    root/.style   = {basic, thin, align=center, fill=box-up!90, double=box-up},
    level 1/.style= {sibling distance=80mm,text width=6cm, text height=5mm},
    level 2/.style = {basic, thin,align=center, fill=box-up!70, text width=8em},
    level 3/.style = {basic, thin, align=center, fill=box-up!50, text width=7em}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
align=center,
edge from parent fork down,
edge from parent/.style={->,draw, rounded corners},
>=latex]

\node[root] {Header}
child {node[level 2] (c1) {Element 1}}
child {node[level 2] (c2) {Element 2}};

\begin{scope}[
anchor = south,
every node/.style={level 3},
edge from parent fork down
]

\node [below right=1em and -3em of c1] (c11) {Element 11};
%\node [below left of = c1] (c12) {Element 12};


\node [below right=1em and -3em of c2] (c21) {Element 21};
\node [below of = c21] (c22) {Element 22};
\node [below of = c22] (c23) {Element 23};
\node [below of = c23] (c24) {Element 24};
\end{scope}

% lines from each level 1 node to every one of its "children"
\draw[->] (c1.south) |- (c11.west);
\draw[->] (c2.south) |- (c21.west);
\draw[->] (c2.south) |- (c22.west);
\draw[->] (c2.south) |- (c23.west);
\draw[->] (c2.south) |- (c24.west);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hej! Thanks for editing my code, I appreciate that very much! Could you still show me how to get that additional raw like in the picture with the four nodes next to each other? I added Level 4 and tried it, but it didn't work like it should be

Comment: suggest ask a fresh question to attract a larger audience